# How to install sonatype/nexus in docker container with ssl

Tags: nexus

How to install sonatype/nexus in docker container with ssl

I couldn't able to configure docker nexus with self signed certificate. Please anyone provide procedure.

Comment: Have your read the [related documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/security/configuring-ssl#ConfiguringSSL-InboundSSL-ConfiguringtoServeContentviaHTTPS) ? With docker, the easiest way is to deploy a side reverse proxy container (nginx, apache...) which will do the SSL termination. This is quite easy to automate with docker-compose.

Comment: Thank you. It's really helped.